# math.acos math domain error within the range of acos

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I've got a script that runs through a set of coordinates for triangles and determines whether or not they're a right triangle.  Part of this uses the cosine rule, and I've come across a problem when checking a certain set of points that happen to fall in a line.  Here's the part that is causing problems:

```
s1 = math.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y1)**2))
s2 = math.sqrt(((x3-x2)**2)+((y3-y2)**2))
s3 = math.sqrt(((x3-x1)**2)+((y3-y1)**2))
num1 = (s1**2)+(s2**2)-(s3**2)
den1 = (2)*(s1)*(s2)
theta1 = math.acos(num1/den1)
num2 = (s1**2)+(s3**2)-(s2**2)
den2 = (2)*(s1)*(s3)
theta2 = math.acos(num2/den2)
num3 = (s3**2)+(s2**2)-(s1**2)
den3 = (2)*(s3)*(s2)
theta3 = math.acos(num3/den3)
```

When I run this through with the three points ([0,0],[4,4],[1,1]), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./i091.py", line 79, in <module>
    detect_right_triangle(xy1, xy2, xy3)
File "./i091.py", line 50, in detect_right_triangle
    theta2 = math.acos(num2/den2)
ValueError: math domain error
```

Just to be sure that I wasn't going outside of the bounds of the cosine function, I had it print the numerator and denominator of theta2 for all of the assessed points, and got this leading up to the point in question:

```
***** [[0, 0], [4, 2], [1, 1]]
>>> num2 =  12.0
>>> den2 =  12.6491106407
***** [[0, 0], [4, 3], [1, 1]]
>>> num2 =  14.0
>>> den2 =  14.1421356237
***** [[0, 0], [4, 4], [1, 1]]
>>> num2 =  16.0
>>> den2 =  16.0
```

I would've thought that there was a problem with dividing two numbers that were the same for whatever reason (16.0), but it worked fine on [2,2] and [3,3] for the second point:

```
***** [[0, 0], [2, 2], [1, 1]]
>>> num2 =  8.0
>>> den2 =  8.0
```

...

```
***** [[0, 0], [3, 3], [1, 1]]
>>> num2 =  12.0
>>> den2 =  12.0
```

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that you are seeing rounding in your floating-point numbers, and that the ratio is actually just over 1.0.

Comment: Do you know how I could expand my output to see the rounding error, or how I could adjust for it?

Comment: I get right results with your numbers. Are you sure the problem is around those numbers? Did you try to compute the acos manually starting from those numbers? Are you sure that in the script some of the numbers do not remain integer?

Comment: There is a built-in function `round()` - use a number of significant places smaller than your platform precision.

Comment: If you run the code, num2 is 16.00000000000001 and den2 is 16.000000000000004 (on my system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code:

```
import math

def foo(x, y):
    x1, x2, x3 = x
    y1, y2, y3 = y
    s1 = math.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y1)**2))
    s2 = math.sqrt(((x3-x2)**2)+((y3-y2)**2))
    s3 = math.sqrt(((x3-x1)**2)+((y3-y1)**2))
    num1 = (s1**2)+(s2**2)-(s3**2)
    den1 = (2)*(s1)*(s2)
    theta1 = math.acos(num1/den1)
    num2 = (s1**2)+(s3**2)-(s2**2)
    den2 = (2)*(s1)*(s3)
    print repr(num2), repr(den2)
    print repr(num2 / den2)
    theta2 = math.acos(num2/den2)
    num3 = (s3**2)+(s2**2)-(s1**2)
    den3 = (2)*(s3)*(s2)
    theta3 = math.acos(num3/den3)

foo([0, 4, 1], [0, 4, 1])
```

I get that `num2/den2 == 1.0000000000000004`.  Unless you print out the full precision, you might not notice that `num2` is *slightly* bigger than `den2` which results in a value slightly bigger than one.  Obviously, since the maximum of cosine is 1, then you can't take the arcos of a number *larger* than 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  For anyone in the future, I used the ceiling function to cap off the rounding error, with a check to ensure that it wouldn't round something to zero over zero.